# Automatically decide document type

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a large database with two different types of documents and I want them to be indexed in ES as different document types in ES terms as well. But I don't want to prefilter my database.

Is it possible to configure ES so it will set the type of the documents according to its structure during indexing?

To give more information:

I'm indexing tweets from the twitter api. But I not only have tweets in json format but also json documents which say to delete a tweet in the database.
I want to index these two documents so that they are unique. For the tweets I ensure that by setting the tweet ID to the document ID with a mapping. But I can't do the same on the delete docs because then I would overwrite the tweets. Separating the two by setting them to different docs but both use the same ID would ensure that, but I'm open for other suggestions.

The delete docs look like this:

```
{"delete":
    {"status":
        {"id":417427762463649792,
        "user_id":608116073,
        "id_str": "417427762463649792",
        "user_id_str":"608116073"}
    }
}
```

And the tweets like this(excerpt):

```
{"created_at":
    "Sun Dec 29 22:59:59 +0000 2013",
    "id":417429821849743360
[...]
}
```

I want to index with stream2es or elasticsearch-hadoop.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share some info as to the differences between the two document types? And how are you planning on loading the data?

Comment: I added information, please tell me if you need to know something else.